# Data structure to implement reverse functionality of a dictionary

Tags: python

Data structure to implement reverse functionality of a dictionary, That is more than one key map to a common value using Python. If am parsing a sentence for example - "The plan was good and well executed ", so I want the group of words {"good", "well" } map to a single entity {"possitivity"}. Using Python

Comment: What do you mean by reverse functionality here? Because in a dictionary you can do something like this: `{'good': 'positivity', 'well': 'positivity'}`, or with a tuple as the key:  `{('good', 'well'): 'positivity'}`

Comment: I have tried dictionary  keeping tupple as a key but it is not working until all the tupple matches.Example = wordpower = { ("best" , "up" , "awesome" , "fantastic" , "happy" , "better" , "best" , "wonderful" , "good" ) : "possitive"} , but not getting desired result . Until all the words in tupple matches the value is not displayed.

Comment: Then you can use the first approach in my comments? Or, that is also not usable?

Comment: @AKS ,It was a simple example - but there are cases where i want more than 20 words to MAP to  a single value . but by using 1st appraoch i have to write many repetition ,

Comment: @SagarRajSingh you can map `positivity` to a tuple containing *all* the words you want to map to.

Comment: @r3ign thanks but i want reverse of it , thats why i asked the question

Comment: if anyone can suggest different data structure for this query

Comment: @SagarRajSingh how about this dictionary: `{('good','well','great','nice') : 'positivity'}` ?

Comment: do anyone have idea about frozenset is it helpful

Comment: @r3ign it is not working correctly , suppose if in a sentence only "good" and "well" words are used that it not giving the value "possitivity" , by using tupple as a key it will require entire tupple values to match in order to get the value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid repetition you can initialize a primary dictionary with tuples as suggested in the comments, then "reverse" it into another dictionary before you use it. As follows:

```
wordpower = {
        "positive": ("best" , "up" , "awesome" , "fantastic" , "happy" , "better" , "wonderful" , "good" ),
        "negative": ("worst" , "down" , "terrible" , "horrible" , "sad" , "worse" , "dreadful" , "bad" )
        }
reverse = {}
for k, v in wordpower.iteritems():
    for word in v:
        reverse[word] = k
pprint(reverse)
```

This will print the following:

```
{'awesome': 'positive',
 'bad': 'negative',
 'best': 'positive',
 'better': 'positive',
 'down': 'negative',
 'dreadful': 'negative',
 'fantastic': 'positive',
 'good': 'positive',
 'happy': 'positive',
 'horrible': 'negative',
 'sad': 'negative',
 'terrible': 'negative',
 'up': 'positive',
 'wonderful': 'positive',
 'worse': 'negative',
 'worst': 'negative'}
```

Comment: Thanks i guess it should work

Comment: but is there any way to map different keys to a single value , by using different data structure other than dictionary

Comment: @SagarRajSingh Not that I know of. You could add your values to a list and refer to an index in that list in the dictionary instead of directly to a value though.